# JQuery request aborted - method called twice in Spring MVC controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring

I've been stuck on this problem for 3 days now, and can't find any helpful information online.

Here is my problem :
I have a .jsp page displaying a list (in my controller, this is handled by @RequestMapping(value = "list"). When clicking on one of these items, I'm trying to display a div to show the details of the item. 
I use JQuery $ajax to send a request to the server to read the database (in my controller, this is handled by @RequestMapping(value = "getCompany")).

The issue I have is the request sent by JQuery aborts (type "NS_BINDING_ABORTED" in HttpFox). It's working fine when I enter the URL manually in my browser.

I noticed something that seems strange to me : when the request is sent to the controller, it executes the method (getCompany), return the result (using @ResponseBody), but right after the "list" method is invoked despite I have no redirection instruction. Could the unwanted redirection be the cause of the aborted JQuery request ? Does somebody know how to avoid this redirection ?

In my understanding, the getCompany method should just add its result to the response.

Thank you for your help !

Here is my script :

```
     $(document).ready(function(){

     //F1
     $(".company").click(function(){

         var id = this.id;

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url : 'getCompany',
                data: {companyId:id},

                success : function(jqXHR, textStatus)
                {
                    alert("success");
                        var json = '${jsonCompany}';
                },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            console.log(jqXHR.status, textStatus, errorThrown);
                                },

                        complete : function(result, status)
                        {

                            var json = '${jsonCompany}';
                        }
        }); 
     }) //End F1
```

and my controller :

```
@Controller("company")
public class CompanyController extends CommonController{

CompanyService companyService; 


/** to company.jsp */
@RequestMapping(value = "list")
public ModelAndView manageCompanies()
{
    mav.clear();
    mav.addObject("companiesList", getCompaniesList());
    mav.addObject("companyForm",new CompanyForm());
    mav.setViewName("admin/company");
    return mav;
}

/** @return company */ 
@RequestMapping(value = "getCompany")
public @ResponseBody String           getCompany(@RequestParam(value="companyId",    required = true) String companyId)
{
    Company company = companyService.getCompany(new Integer(companyId));
    return companyService.toJSON(company).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason of my problem, if it can help some others. The item of the list (a basic `<td>`) used to invoke the $ajax GET had a link on it (`<a href"">`) and was submitting the url displayed in the browser => not a "wierd" redirection problem. And answer to one of my question : yes, sending two requests at the same time (or almost) will kill one of the request (in my case, the $ajax one).